# channel iterator partially covered [1 of 2 branches] kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, amazon-sqs, kotlin-coroutines, kover

I have written a custom SQS consumer wherein :

- One coroutine that periodically retrieves the messages
- Multiple workers that process the receiving messages in parallel without blocking.
- A channel to communicate between the MsgReceiver coroutine and the Workers.

However, when writing unit tests I am unable to achieve 100% test coverage `kover` or with `sonar`. The kover/sonar plugin complains about partially covered while loop [highlighted in yellow] and I cannot understand which scenario have I missed

Unit test cases:

1. When Single message
2. When no message
3. When 10+ message
4. when "no more" message after polling once
5. When an error

Actual code :

[image]

I looked inside of itr.hasnext() method and there are several branches but unable to understand why code coverage is considering internal methods of the library for code coverage ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you cover both error cases; when the exception is the JsonParseExcception and when it's something else?

Comment: yeah.. those are covered

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

Basically, the hasNext() method from `AbstractChannel` class never returned false.

[image]

So, mocked the channel, wrote a custom iterator and made `hasNext()` return false

```
val mockChannel: Channel<Message> = mock()
whenever(mockChannel.iterator()).thenReturn(Itr())
```

[image]

And it worked like a charm

[image]